# Powershell pass code to a function, add -errorAction and process in try/catch block

Tags: powershell

I have a scenario where I am doing any number of things with a network resource, copying files or folders, deleting a ZIP file after it has been unzipped locally, checking an EXE to see if it was downloaded from the internet and needs unblocked, running a software install, etc. And all of these tasks are impacted by things like an installer that hasn't released a file lock on a log file to be deleted, or the unzip hasn't released the file lock on the zip file, or the network is for a fleeting moment "unavailable" so a network file is not found.
I have a technique that works well for handling this scenario, I do a loop and react to the specific exception, and when that exception occurs I just sleep for 6 seconds. The loop happens up to 10 times before I abandon. Here is the code for dealing with an Autodesk log that is still locked by the Autodesk installer.

```
        $waitRetryCount = 10
        :waitForAccess do { 
            try { 
                Remove-Item $odisLogPath -Recurse -errorAction:Stop
                $retry = $False
            } catch {
                if (($PSItem.Exception -is [System.IO.IOException]) -or ($PSItem.Exception.InnerException -and ($PSItem.Exception.InnerException -is [System.IO.IOException]))) {
                    if ($waitRetryCount -eq 0) {
                        $invokeODISLogManagement.log.Add('E_Error deleting ODIS logs: retry limit exceeded')
                        break waitForFolderAccess
                    } else {
                        $retry = $True
                        $waitRetryCount --
                        Start-Sleep -s:6
                    }
                } else {
                    $invokeODISLogManagement.log.Add('E_Error deleting ODIS logs')
                    $invokeODISLogManagement.log.Add("=_$($PSItem.Exception.GetType().FullName)")
                    $invokeODISLogManagement.log.Add("=_$($PSItem.Exception.Message)")
                    if ($PSItem.Exception.InnerException) {
                        $invokeODISLogManagement.log.Add("=_$($PSItem.Exception.InnerException.GetType().FullName)")
                        $invokeODISLogManagement.log.Add("=_$($PSItem.Exception.InnerException.Message)")
                    }
                    $retry = $False
                }
            }
        } while ($retry)
```

The thing is, I would like to convert this to a function, since it needs to be handled in a lot of places. So I would need to pass to the function the specific exception I am looking for and the code to be run in the try block, and get back a log (as a `generic.list`) that I can then add to the actual log list. The first and last aspects I have, but I am unsure the best approach for the code to `try`. In the above example it is a single line, `Remove-Item $odisLogPath -Recurse -errorAction:Stop`, but it could be multiple lines I suspect.

To start playing with this I verified that this does seem to work, at least with a single line of code.

```
$code = {Get-Item '\\noServer\folder\file.txt' -errorAction:Stop}
try {
    & $code 
} catch {
    Write-Host "$($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)"
}
```

But the error action is going to be duplicated a lot, so I thought to maybe address that within the function, however
$code = {Get-Item '\noServer\folder\file.txt'}

```
try {
    & $code -errorAction:Stop
} catch {
    Write-Host "$($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)"
}
```

does NOT work. I get the exception uncaught.

So, my questions are
1: Is this the right direction? I am pretty sure it is but perhaps someone has a gotcha that I am not seeing, yet. :)
2: Is there a mechanism to add the `-errorAction:Stop` in the `try`, so I don't need to do it/remember to do it, at every use of this new function.
3: I seem to remember reading about a programming concept of passing code to a function, and I can't remember what that is called, but I would like to know the generic term. Indeed, it probably would help if I could tag it for this post. I had thought it might be lama, but a quick search suggests that is not the case? Being self taught sucks sometimes.

EDIT:
I have now implemented a function, that starts to do what I want.

```
function Invoke-PxWaitForAccess {
    param (
        [System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock]$code,
        [String]$path
    )

    try {
        (& $code -path $path)
    } catch {
        Return "$($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)!!"
    }
}


$path = '\\noServer\folder\file.txt'
$code = {param ([String]$path) Write-Host "$path!"; Get-Item $path}
Invoke-PxWaitForAccess -code $code -path $path
```

I do wonder if the path couldn't somehow be encapsulated in the `$code` variable itself, since this implementation means it can ONLY be used where the code being run has a single variable called `$path`.

And, still wondering if this really is the best, or even a good, way to proceed? Or are there arguments for just implementing my loop 50 some odd times in all the situations where I need this behavior.

Also worth noting that this code does not yet implement the loop or address the fact that different exceptions apply in different situations.

EDIT #2:
And here is a more complete implementation, though it fails because it seems I am not actually passing a type, even though it looks like I am. So I get an error because what is to the right of `-is` must be an actual type.

```
function Invoke-PxWaitForAccess {
    param (
        [System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock]$code,
        [String]$path,
        [Type]$exceptionType
    )

    $invokeWaitForAccess = @{
        success = $Null
        log = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]::new()
    }

    $waitRetryCount = 2
    :waitForAccess do { 
        try { 
            Write-Host "$path ($waitRetryCount)"
            & $code -path $path
            $retry = $False
        } catch {
            Write-Host "!$($PSItem.Exception.GetType().FullName)"
            if (($PSItem.Exception -is $exceptionType) -or ($PSItem.Exception.InnerException -and ($PSItem.Exception.InnerException -is $exceptionType))) {
                Write-Host "($waitRetryCount)"
                if ($waitRetryCount -eq 0) {
                    $invokeWaitForAccess.log.Add('E_retry limit exceeded')
                    break waitForFolderAccess
                } else {
                    $retry = $True
                    $waitRetryCount --
                    Start-Sleep -s:6
                }
            } else {
                $invokeWaitForAccess.log.Add("=_$($PSItem.Exception.GetType().FullName)")
                $invokeWaitForAccess.log.Add("=_$($PSItem.Exception.Message)")
                if ($PSItem.Exception.InnerException) {
                    $invokeWaitForAccess.log.Add("=_$($PSItem.Exception.InnerException.GetType().FullName)")
                    $invokeWaitForAccess.log.Add("=_$($PSItem.Exception.InnerException.Message)")
                }
                $retry = $False
            }
        }
    } while ($retry)

    if ($invokeWaitForAccess.log.Count -eq 0) {
        $invokeWaitForAccess.success = $True
    } else {
        $invokeWaitForAccess.success = $False
    }

    return $invokeWaitForAccess
}


$path = '\\noServer\folder\file.txt'
$code = {param ([String]$path) Get-Item $path -errorAction:Stop}
if ($invoke = (Invoke-PxWaitForAccess -code $code -path $path -type ([System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException])).success) {
    Write-Host 'Good'
} else {
    foreach ($line in $invoke.log) {
        Write-Host "$line"
    }
}
```

EDIT #3: This is what I have now, and it seems to work fine. But the code I am passing will sometimes be something like `Remove-Object` and the error is `[System.IO.IOException]`, but at other times I actually need to return more than an error, like here where the code involves `Get-Item`. And that means defining the code block outside the function with a reference to the variable inside the function, which seems, fugly,  to me. It may be that what I am trying to do is just more complicated than PowerShell is really designed to handle, but it seems MUCH more likely that there is a more elegant way to do what I am trying to do? Without being able to manipulate the script block from within the function I don't see any good options.
For what it is worth this last example shows a failure where the exception I am accepting for the repeat occurs and hits the limit, as well as an exception that just immediately fails because it is not the exception I am looping on, and an example where I return something. A fourth condition would be when I am trying to delete, and waiting on `[System.IO.IOException]` and a success would return nothing, no item, and no error log.

```
function Invoke-PxWaitForAccess {
    param (
        [System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock]$code,
        [String]$path,
        [Type]$exceptionType
    )

    $invokeWaitForAccess = @{
        item = $null
        errorLog = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]::new()
    }

    $waitRetryCount = 2
    :waitForSuccess do { 
        try { 
            & $code -path $path
            $retry = $False
        } catch {
            if (($PSItem.Exception -is $exceptionType) -or ($PSItem.Exception.InnerException -and ($PSItem.Exception.InnerException -is $exceptionType))) {
                if ($waitRetryCount -eq 0) {
                    $invokeWaitForAccess.errorLog.Add('E_Retry limit exceeded')
                    break waitForSuccess
                } else {
                    $retry = $True
                    $waitRetryCount --
                    Start-Sleep -s:6
                }
            } else {
                $invokeWaitForAccess.errorLog.Add("=_$($PSItem.Exception.GetType().FullName)")
                $invokeWaitForAccess.errorLog.Add("=_$($PSItem.Exception.Message)")
                if ($PSItem.Exception.InnerException) {
                    $invokeWaitForAccess.errorLog.Add("=_$($PSItem.Exception.InnerException.GetType().FullName)")
                    $invokeWaitForAccess.errorLog.Add("=_$($PSItem.Exception.InnerException.Message)")
                }
                $retry = $False
            }
        }
    } while ($retry)
    
    return $invokeWaitForAccess
}

CLS
$path = '\\noServer\folder\file.txt'
$code = {param ([String]$path) Get-Item $path -errorAction:Stop}
$invoke = (Invoke-PxWaitForAccess -code $code -path $path -exceptionType:([System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]))
if ($invoke.errorLog.count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "Good $path"
} else {
    foreach ($line in $invoke.errorLog) {
        Write-Host "$line"
    }
}
Write-Host
$path = '\\noServer\folder\file.txt'
$code = {param ([String]$path) Get-Item $path -errorAction:Stop}
$invoke = (Invoke-PxWaitForAccess -code $code -path $path -exceptionType:([System.IO.IOException]))
if ($invoke.errorLog.count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "Good $path"
} else {
    foreach ($line in $invoke.errorLog) {
        Write-Host "$line"
    }
}
Write-Host
$path = '\\Mac\iCloud Drive\Px Tools 3.#\# Dev 3.4.5\Definitions.xml'
$code = {param ([String]$path) $invokeWaitForAccess.item = Get-Item $path -errorAction:Stop}
$invoke = (Invoke-PxWaitForAccess -code $code -path $path -exceptionType:([System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]))
if ($invoke.errorLog.count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "Good $path !"
    Write-Host "$($invoke.item)"
} else {
    foreach ($line in $invoke.errorLog) {
        Write-Host "$line"
    }
}
Write-Host
```

Comment: If you want a function, make it a function? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: @scepticalist I am making it a function now, but just the concept of passing code to a function as a solution was something I wasn't sure of. I am going to revise the OP now to show the function based approach, at least as I have it now.